# How do I create a new linode and move my current websites and data to it?

Tags: lamp, ubuntu-9.10, linode

I am a relative newby to managing my own server. I set up a Linode a while ago, installed Ubuntu 9.1 (Karmic) followed by Apache, MySQL, my websites, some mods etc.

What I didn't realise was that, not only could I upgrade my version of Ubuntu, but that I should. I now find myself with an unsupported version of Ubuntu and a lot of stuff sitting on top of it.

It seems that the recommended process for [EOL upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) is actually to reinstall rather than to upgrade.

I was thinking of setting up a brand new Linode on the latest version of Ubuntu and then moving all my stuff across.

The question is though:

- What should I move across?
- What is the best way to do it?

Comment: That's not true about upgrading, from a karmic you can upgrade to 10.04 that its the current LTS, and it's supported. Can you detail exactly what kind of application you need to move on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Linode you can easily make a clone of your actual vps, try to upgrade to Lucid on the clone and check that everything is working fine. If it's ok, you can repeat the upgrading steps on the main vps, and destroy the clone as the last step.

You should be able to swap ip address of the master and clone if you want to use straight the clone without repeating the upgrade procedure on the master.

Comment: I've done what you recommend and it seems to have worked like a charm. I just can't work out how I am to swap ip addresses.

Comment: Found it under "Remote Access"

Comment: Compliments, you have just entered in the virtualizaton wonderland.